# convert specific columns to rows based on condition pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe as shown below..

```
E     F     G     H     I     J
U902E U902F U902G U902H U902I U902J
U997E U997F U997G U997H U997I U997J
```

I want the following result:
for each column value, I have to get all the corresponding columns to be in a rows(transpose) except the selected column value, that is:

```
A     B
U902E U902F
U902E U902G
U902E U902H
U902E U902I
U902E U902J
U902F U902E
U902F U902G
U902F U902H
U902F U902I
U902F U902J
U902G U902E
U902G U902F
U902G U902H
U902G U902I
U902G U902J
U902H U902E
U902H U902F
U902H U902G
U902H U902I
U902H U902J
U902I U902E
U902I U902F
U902I U902G
U902I U902H
U902I U902J
U902J U902E
U902J U902F
U902J U902G
U902J U902H
U902J U902I
```

I have shown it only for 1st row of input. I want it for all the rows of the input dataframe.

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Where does a and b suddenly come from?

Comment: Those are just column header names.. you can use any name...

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is permutations, which is part of the `itertools`.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations
permuts = list(permutations(df.iloc[0], 2))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(permuts, columns=["A","B"])
```

Comment: But what if i want for all the rows of input?? The above code works well only for the first row

Comment: I'm not doing your homework here. You should be able to figure out the rest on your own ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use, learn, and improvise the example from @JanZeiseweis (using the `itertools` module). `combinations` and `permutations` are useful in working with *sets* of data.

---

Another way, you could also use *loops* as below example :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'Num':['1','2','3'], 'Let':['a','b','c']});
```

then we have `df` as

```
    Let Num
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
```

now take only the first column (in yours will be row).

`L=df['Let']`

`L`

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: Let, dtype: object
```

Since the output you wanted has *simple pattern*, you may take pairs *iteratively* as illustrated below :

```
for i in L.index:
    for j in L.index:
        if i != j:
            print(str(L[i])+' '+str(L[j]));
```

The result of this example :

```
a b
a c
b a
b c
c a
c b
```

Now you may improvise from this example to solve your problem. Hope this helps.